# jquery ajax result. Get "return-data" at textStatus timeout?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I'm trying to read an RSS-feed with $.ajax. 
Reading the file is fairly simple, but I actually need just the first few item and not the whole rss with it's several hundreds:

I tried to handle the ajax-"return object" - the jqXHR - as if it would be a stream.
It seams that there's no way that I can read the file which gets written at the time.

So I added a timeout to my $.ajax-request:
If the "complete" is "timeout" I would like to parse the jqHXR anyway, which got loaded before the timout kicked in.

But I can't figure out how to get the "result" of the request.
I mean, there must be some sort of object which gets filled by the $.ajax-function?

Thanks!

Comment: The question is not clear enough for me to respond without seeing some example code.

Comment: I have no idea how I could make this even more clear.

Comment: https://github.com/richifrick/jQuery.progressiveAjax
I came up with this solution... In case anybody else needs to handle a ajax-response like a stream